# Sending alert from bluegiga dongle to android handset

Tags: android, api, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to develop a BLE bluetooth (SMART) application for Android.I am using the [Broadcom-ble API](http://code.google.com/p/broadcom-ble/)

I have a requirement to send alerts from Bluegiga dongle to the android handset. I send alert values such as 0,1,2 from bluegiga. Whenever I send the alert, the following callback is invoked inside my application:

```
@Override
public void onCharacteristicWrite(String address, BleCharacteristic charObj) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCharacteristicWrite(" + address + ", " + charObj + ")");

}
```

The following line of code gives nullpointer, when I try to fetch the alert value from the charObj

```
byte alertLevel = charObj.getValue()[0];
```

I have checked and confirmed, charObj is not null. But charObj.getValue() returns null.

Can someone please let me know, though the callback is invoked correctly when I send an alert from bluegiga, why I am unable to retrieve the sent value, from my application?

Any help is appreciated.